# Setting up Bitcoin Cash testnet

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I am new Bitcoin cash wallet development :
--I want to create or sync with existing bitcoin cash testnet for my testing but don't find a way.
--If available testnet insight for bitcoin cash.

Kindly suggest how can i achieve this. Any Help is appreciated

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57785/is-there-an-active-testnet-for-bitcoin-cash

Comment: By "insight" do you mean you are looking for a block explorer?  There is one at https://www.blocktrail.com/tBCC.  If not, please clarify your question.